# Recreating CheckedTextView's Functionality

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to recreate the CheckedTextView's functionality using my own custom views so I can have two TextViews on the left with a CheckBox on the right, centered vertically between the two TextViews. I have the Layout working for it, which I will include below. I also have it so that when you click on the outer LinearLayout (LinearLayout1) it will pass that click to the checkbox. The only thing that I can't figure out is when you press down on a checkbox it briefly highlights the checkbox (in yellow on my device) before marking it checked. I'd like to have it do the same if you touch anywhere on the outer LinearLayout, but I don't know where I'd need to hook in to make that happen.

Here is my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/FieldValueTextView"
            android:text="Value"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/FieldLabelTextView"
            android:text="Label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/LinearLayout2"
        android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I can't understand your problem clearly friend! Can you say exactly whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was experiencing was solved by putting the following android:focusable="false" on the CheckBox and the two TextViews so that when the ListView is clicked, it gets the focus, not the inner views.

Hope that helps someone else.